# How to create a Detail button with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am currently creating a new component on reactJS that needs to show the details of only a specific user that is clicked in another component. However, I am facing problems with trying to gather the data from the backend to the frontend.

Here is the component that shows the list of all the users (consultants.component.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './consultants.component.css'
import axios from 'axios';

const Consultant = props => (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.consultant.employee_name}</td>
        <td>{props.consultant.employee_title}</td>

        <td>
            <NavLink to={'/detail_consultant/'+props.consultant._id}><button className='btn btn-info ml-auto'>details</button></NavLink>
        </td>
    </tr>
)

export default class ConsultantList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {consultants: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/consultants/')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ consultants: response.data })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    }

    consultantList() {
        return this.state.consultants.map(currentconsultants => {
            return <Consultant consultant={currentconsultants} key={currentconsultants._id}/>;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='consultant-page'>
                <h3>List of Consultants</h3>
                <table className='table-responsive'>
                    <thead className='table table-striped'>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope='col'>Employee Name</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Title</th>
                            <th scope='col'>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.consultantList() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

When the user clicks on a specific row from the all users table, its specific id is passed in the url and the user is also redirected to another component.
Below is the component that is supposed to show the details of the specific user clicked:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const Consultant_information = props => (
    <div>
        <p>Employee Name: {props.consultant_information.employee_name}</p>
        <p>Employee Title: {props.consultant_information.title}</p>
    </div>
)

export default class Detail_consultant extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {consultants: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/consultants/' + this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ consultants: response.data })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    detailConsultant() {
        return this.state.consultants.map(currentconsultant => {
            return <Consultant_information consultant_information={currentconsultant} key={currentconsultant._id}/>;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='consultant-page'>
                { this.detailConsultant() }
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I already tested the get/:id with Insomnia and it is working fine, so the problem must be in the front-end.

[Here is the error that I am currently getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbg0N.png)

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What data do you get back? Did you check the requests in the Network tab of dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the data got back from the backend, in your Axios request within the componentDidmount Lifecycle method in `Detail_consultant component` is an Array. The stack trace suggests that `response.data` is not an array and maybe an Object which does not have the method `.map()` in its prototype. If it is an Object, target the Array within the `response.data` the set that in the state and everything will run accordingly. An example would be:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/consultants/' + this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(response => { 
            this.setState({ consultants: response })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
However, doing the suggested change above I get other error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: can you please post the response you get from Insomnia when making a query to `get/:id`

Comment: Since the response is an array the solution to fix the issue is:
```
this.setState({ consultants: response })
```
inside the `componentDidMount` and not as depicted above, let me edit the
answer accordingly.